# Have Problem with Insert syntax sentence How to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, insert

Hello guys i am doing a website, I have a problem with my Insert syntax sentence can anyone help me to find the problem that i have in my sentence?

```
using (OleDbConnection sqlCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                string query = "INSERT INTO SoccerAchievements (PlayerCode,TeamCode,Achievement,When) VALUES (@PlayerCode,@TeamCode,@Achievement,@When)";
                OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerCode", (AdminBook.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPlayerCodeFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamCode", (AdminBook.FooterRow.FindControl("txtTeamCodeFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Achievement", (AdminBook.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAchievementFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@When", (AdminBook.FooterRow.FindControl("txtWhenFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                PopulateGridView();
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "נתון חדש נוסף בהצלחה";
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

I want it to insert to my database and its give me error that i have syntax problem with my insert sentence

Comment: Are you using Access database or other OLE DB provider? AFAIK `When` may be a keyword; try wrapping it in brackets like `[When]`.

Comment: Could you provide the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: Also https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: I am using access database

Comment: Thank you bro it worked, I changed The word to WhenHappend

Answer (score 2):

According to [Access reserved words list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2), `WHEN` used as reserved word, hence you need to wrap it inside brackets:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO SoccerAchievements (PlayerCode, TeamCode, Achievement, [When]) 
                VALUES (@PlayerCode, @TeamCode, @Achievement, @When)";
```

Also you need to use `Add()` instead of `AddWithValue()` to provide parameter values.